# best practice for multi-project c# solution

Tags: c#, solution, multi-project

I am maintaining a C# solution consisting for multi-project. It's usually no problem altering any project except on project `z`, which gets referenced in a few other project in the solution and also in project `a` and `b`.

Project `a` uses the main GUI whereas project `b` and `z` are referenced in project `a`. When project `z` is changed and built, I get mismatch of version.

I currently use references and post build script to copy the output to the right project. I did this because it usually saves a lot of compile and build time.

I'm getting tired of manually correcting the problem with manual copy of project `z` output to `b` and `a`.

I guess it's a tossup to allow debugging or not. I normally don't need debugging on project `z` and hence I use reference on the `z's` any CPU release build in many places.

Any suggestion to improve on this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are referencing a specific version of the dll, and when you update the dll with a new version, the version's don't match.

The best way to solve this problem is to reference projects b and z directly.

Remove the existing references from project a, and add new references.

When you add the new reference, there is an option to add a project reference, choose that option.

The build mechanism will automatically copy the appropriate dll's out for you.

Comment: so I can remove the post build script for project b and z? and use project references for b and z in project as well as project ref for z in project B? btw project b does build an standlone exe with it's own gui

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Visual Studio can manage all of that for you.